# Using pythonTelegramApi to send Images

Tags: python

I tried sending images from my telegram bot. It sends but it keeps loading and not actually download. It isn't the internet speed(I checked it) please help me out. Here is the code I used.

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('tests/test.png', 'rb'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it keeps loading`? Is it you downloading the picture or the bot sending it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to close the resource after you use it.

try to close it in a With block:

```
with open('tests/test.png', 'rb') as file:
  bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=file)
```